# Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T> / IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable, linq-to-objects

I found an example in the [VS2008 Examples](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx) for Dynamic LINQ that allows you to use a SQL-like string (e.g. `OrderBy("Name, Age DESC"))` for ordering. Unfortunately, the method included only works on `IQueryable<T>`. Is there any way to get this functionality on `IEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 978, accepted):

Just stumbled into this oldie...

To do this without the dynamic LINQ library, you just need the code as below. This covers most common scenarios including nested properties.

To get it working with `IEnumerable<T>` you could add some wrapper methods that go via `AsQueryable` - but the code below is the core `Expression` logic needed.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, 
    string property)
{
    return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "OrderBy");
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, 
    string property)
{
    return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "OrderByDescending");
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(
    this IOrderedQueryable<T> source, 
    string property)
{
    return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "ThenBy");
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenByDescending<T>(
    this IOrderedQueryable<T> source, 
    string property)
{
    return ApplyOrder<T>(source, property, "ThenByDescending");
}

static IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyOrder<T>(
    IQueryable<T> source, 
    string property, 
    string methodName) 
{
    string[] props = property.Split('.');
    Type type = typeof(T);
    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    Expression expr = arg;
    foreach(string prop in props) {
        // use reflection (not ComponentModel) to mirror LINQ
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop);
        expr = Expression.Property(expr, pi);
        type = pi.PropertyType;
    }
    Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), type);
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr, arg);

    object result = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(
            method => method.Name == methodName
                    && method.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                    && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
                    && method.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), type)
            .Invoke(null, new object[] {source, lambda});
    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)result;
}
```

---

Edit: it gets more fun if you want to mix that with `dynamic` - although note that `dynamic` only applies to LINQ-to-Objects (expression-trees for ORMs etc can't really represent `dynamic` queries - `MemberExpression` doesn't support it). But here's a way to do it with LINQ-to-Objects. Note that the choice of `Hashtable` is due to favorable locking semantics:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
static class Program
{
    private static class AccessorCache
    {
        private static readonly Hashtable accessors = new Hashtable();

        private static readonly Hashtable callSites = new Hashtable();

        private static CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>> GetCallSiteLocked(
            string name) 
        {
            var callSite = (CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>)callSites[name];
            if(callSite == null)
            {
                callSites[name] = callSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>
                    .Create(Binder.GetMember(
                                CSharpBinderFlags.None, 
                                name, 
                                typeof(AccessorCache),
                                new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { 
                                    CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(
                                        CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, 
                                        null) 
                                }));
            }
            return callSite;
        }

        internal static Func<dynamic,object> GetAccessor(string name)
        {
            Func<dynamic, object> accessor = (Func<dynamic, object>)accessors[name];
            if (accessor == null)
            {
                lock (accessors )
                {
                    accessor = (Func<dynamic, object>)accessors[name];
                    if (accessor == null)
                    {
                        if(name.IndexOf('.') >= 0) {
                            string[] props = name.Split('.');
                            CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>[] arr 
                                = Array.ConvertAll(props, GetCallSiteLocked);
                            accessor = target =>
                            {
                                object val = (object)target;
                                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    var cs = arr[i];
                                    val = cs.Target(cs, val);
                                }
                                return val;
                            };
                        } else {
                            var callSite = GetCallSiteLocked(name);
                            accessor = target =>
                            {
                                return callSite.Target(callSite, (object)target);
                            };
                        }
                        accessors[name] = accessor;
                    }
                }
            }
            return accessor;
        }
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<dynamic> OrderBy(
        this IEnumerable<dynamic> source, 
        string property)
    {
        return Enumerable.OrderBy<dynamic, object>(
            source, 
            AccessorCache.GetAccessor(property), 
            Comparer<object>.Default);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<dynamic> OrderByDescending(
        this IEnumerable<dynamic> source, 
        string property)
    {
        return Enumerable.OrderByDescending<dynamic, object>(
            source, 
            AccessorCache.GetAccessor(property), 
            Comparer<object>.Default);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<dynamic> ThenBy(
        this IOrderedEnumerable<dynamic> source, 
        string property)
    {
        return Enumerable.ThenBy<dynamic, object>(
            source, 
            AccessorCache.GetAccessor(property), 
            Comparer<object>.Default);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<dynamic> ThenByDescending(
        this IOrderedEnumerable<dynamic> source, 
        string property)
    {
        return Enumerable.ThenByDescending<dynamic, object>(
            source, 
            AccessorCache.GetAccessor(property), 
            Comparer<object>.Default);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic a = new ExpandoObject(), 
                b = new ExpandoObject(), 
                c = new ExpandoObject();
        a.X = "abc";
        b.X = "ghi";
        c.X = "def";
        dynamic[] data = new[] { 
            new { Y = a },
            new { Y = b }, 
            new { Y = c } 
        };

        var ordered = data.OrderByDescending("Y.X").ToArray();
        foreach (var obj in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Y.X);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best damn piece of code I have seen :) 

Just solved a million problems in my project :)

Comment: Marc, Do you have the similar extension for LIKE Condition?

Comment: @Prasad - `LIKE` is a bit different, but which back end? For LINQ-to-SQL, there is `SqlMethods.Like`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx; can you add more info what you are looking for?

Comment: I am using SQL as backend, i need to do a search operation with dynamic parameter names as like in your OrderBy extension.

Comment: Well, you can certainly use `SqlMethods.Like` in a custom expression; it really isn't clear where it breaks down... can you clarify? Perhaps ask as a question?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654745/dynamic-linq-like yesterday. Its better if i have a sample on it

Comment: Sounds like lots of folks had success with this code- I can't for the life of me figure out how to apply it!  These are extension methods, right?  How do I use them??

Comment: @Dave - you need to start with `IQueryable<T>`, so if you have something like `List<T>` (which is `IEnumerable<T>`) you may need to use `AsQueryable()` - for example `var sorted = someList.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Foo.Bar");`

Comment: Have you seen this... it might help some people... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557819/strongly-typed-dynamic-linq-sorting/2794039#2794039 its a more strongly typed solution.

Comment: Great code ! Do you know any way to add support to the "Count()" extension method ?  Calling an extension method is quiet a pain, and I have troubles building an expression with those.
I'm trying to add the 'Count()' support for IQueryable<T> which is coded as extension in the 'Queryable' type.

Comment: @ile - `var ordered = someData.OrderBy("Name");` - or for `IEnumerable<T>` data, `var ordered = someData.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Name");`

Comment: This be done already with *AsQueryAble().OrderBy().ThenBy()*. There must be something I'm missing. **Edit** I just noticed the above methods are returning *IOrderedQueryable* and the methods I listed are returning *IOrderedEnumerable*.

Comment: if  use switch which will be  faster. reflection vs switch

Comment: @Nario - context? switch on *what*, vs *what* reflection? Oh, you mean building up with `.OrderBy(x => x.Something)` (times 10 or whatever) - the `switch`, most likely

Comment: switch(propertyname)
{ 
 case "property1":
   result=datacontex.orderby(x=>x.property1)
 break; 
 case "property2":
   result=datacontex.orderby(x=>x.property2)
 break; 

}

Comment: Thanks for this!  One improvement I have found is, instead of the Reflection GetMethod()..Invoke() statement, you can build the result direcly in linq: var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new[] { source.ElementType, expr.Type }, source.Expression, lambda);

            var result = source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach with an object implementing IDynamicMetaObjectProvider? I'm having issues described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206631/dynamic-sorting-with-a-serializabledynamicobject

Comment: @BonyT no, but I've added a "dynamic" approach to your question

Comment: @MarcGravell: I post a question in this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495873/dynamic-sort-in-linq/12495964 . and the problem is when I use your extension methods the result does not sort. what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code. Same question as Mose: Do you know any way to add support to the "Count()" extension method?

Comment: Is there a way I can apply a sort by a subcollection?

Comment: @ahmed depends... What does that *mean*?

Comment: If anyone is interested, I got it to work with `IEnumerable` simply substituting `lambda` with `lambda.Compile()` in the penultimate line, barring the obvious substitutions `IQueryable` > `IEnumerable` and `IOrderedQueryable` with `IOrderedEnumerable`. No wrappers involved

Comment: Wow, this is ridiculous - a couple of lines of code inflated to forty just to avoid using System.Linq.Dynamic? Is there some kind of advantage to not using it? **Take a look at @Alaa Osta's answer** below (the actual solution to the original question).

Comment: @MGOwen you seem to misunderstand the nature of code. The 40 lines is the same no matter whether it is 40 lines that you put somewhere in your project, or if those lines come (pre-compiled, or as source) in an external library. It would have been *pretty amazing* if I had linked, in Oct '08 to a library on nuget that has existed since Dec '11 (not least because nuget didn't exist then either), but the fundamental "what it is doing" is the same. Also, you use the phrase "actual solution" as though there is some well-defined agreed single route to every coding question: there is not.

Comment: @MGOwen btw, the external lib is 2296 lines of code (not including AssemblyInfo.cs); which kinda makes the 40 lines here look pretty reasonable

Comment: @MarcGravell Ahhh OK, Sorry, didn't notice this answer was so old.  I was just pretty confused, as 99% of people who find this question will be. My comment wasn't directed at you, but at them: the hundreds of people finding this question who need the best answer currently available. WRT lines of code, I think most programmers will prefer to use an established library to solve the problem, and if I understand linking correctly, only the code used will be included anyway, right?

Comment: @MGOwen .net doesn't use a linker (except on some AOT frameworks). All the IL will be included, but only the methods that get used will be JIT-ed

Comment: Nice, just don't rename any of the properties.

Comment: @MarcGravell does this sort before or after the sql is run? I also use paging so that I'll only retrieve a few records at the time, but to get the correct records the sorting must be done in the sql statement, not in memory.

Comment: @Zaphod as long as the input is a suitable `IQueryable<T>`, it is composed into the query without executing anything or doing anything in-memory

Comment: Very nice code, it helped me a lot with ordering by column name stored in string. However it doesn't work all that well with interfaces. I mean if you have a IQueryable of an interface class and try to order by a column that isn't part of the interface you'll get an error. Thankfully it's easy enough to fix. Replacing all instances of typeof(T) with source.ElementType will allow ordering by any column of the actual class that is handled within the query.

Comment: @MarcGravell, In the first snippet you don't need to compute yourself the delegateType of the LambdaExpression. If you don't pass it as first argument it is computed automatically by Expression.Lambda.

Comment: Very nice... In my extremely basic test this executes in 29 ms vs `System.Linq.Dynamic`'s 148 ms.

Comment: I can't understand even single line from this code, but it works!

Comment: I'm using the first part of code and it works very cool. But after changing the project to .net Core 3.0 the nullable-warnings are driving me crazy. Could you please update the code?

Comment: @Henning (places tongue in cheek) - sure! `#nullable disable`

Comment: @MarcGravell Hey master, do I need to escape the input to prevent injections?

Comment: @Nicholas no, the expression-tree parser/SQL generator layer deals with that, as parameters

Answer (score 299):

Too easy without any complication:

1. Add `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` at the top.
2. Use `vehicles = vehicles.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Make ASC, Year DESC").ToList();`

**Edit**: to save some time, the **System.Linq.Dynamic.Core** (System.Linq.Dynamic is deprecated) assembly is not part of the framework, but can be installed from nuget: [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/)

Comment: and where did you get the `System.Linq.Dynamic` from ?

Comment: Works when using linq with MongoDB as well.

Comment: The accepted answer may have been the correct answer in 2008 but currently this is the easiest, most correct answer now.

Comment: This is really good and simple handling, so much complexity internally, loved it

Comment: Is it possible to sort by a nested property?, for example: 
vehicles = vehicles.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Status.Label ASC, Year DESC").ToList();

Comment: I thought the accepted answer was amazing, but this is pure gold!

Comment: For the people in the "future", if you are using dotnet core, use this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: For anybody looking through this as I did for the same solution - this is working for sorting on "Nested" objects, i.e. `vehicles.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Tire.Size").ToList();`, where `Tire` is a object that belongs to `Vehicle`.

Comment: @RafaelMerlin Also the namespace is now System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: How would you sort on included/joined columns ? Is there a way to avoid precising the joined table like @neilsimp1 mentionned ? I'd like something like : `vehicles.Include(v => v.Tire).AsQueryable().OrderBy("Size ASC").ToList()`

Answer (score 61):

Just stumbled across this question.

Using Marc's ApplyOrder implementation from above, I slapped together an Extension method that handles SQL-like strings like:

```
list.OrderBy("MyProperty DESC, MyOtherProperty ASC");
```

Details can be found here: http://aonnull.blogspot.com/2010/08/dynamic-sql-like-linq-orderby-extension.html

Comment: Great stuff, just add a modification as follows to make the property name case insensitive:

PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop,BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 49):

I guess it would work to use reflection to get whatever property you want to sort on:

```
IEnumerable<T> myEnumerables
var query=from enumerable in myenumerables
          where some criteria
          orderby GetPropertyValue(enumerable,"SomeProperty")
          select enumerable

private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string property)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo=obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Note that using reflection is considerably slower than accessing the property directly, so the performance would have to be investigated.

Comment: does this even work? orderby does not want a value but a selector lamba/delegate (Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)..

Comment: I did try this example before posting it, and yes, it does work.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was looking for!  This will work great for simple page sorting issues.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Am I missing something? What should "SomeProperty" be. I tried giving the property name as well as property.GetType(). I have IQueryable<> and not IEnumerable<>

Comment: GetPropertyValue mehotod will be executed for all elements, it's bad solution.

Comment: @Alex Shkor: How are you supposed to sort the elements without looking at all the elements? However, there are better solutions in other answers.

Answer (score 22):

Just building on what others have said. I found that the following works quite well.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, string queryString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
        return input;

    int i = 0;
    foreach (string propname in queryString.Split(','))
    {
        var subContent = propname.Split('|');
        if (Convert.ToInt32(subContent[1].Trim()) == 0)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                input = input.OrderBy(x => GetPropertyValue(x, subContent[0].Trim()));
            else
                input = ((IOrderedEnumerable<T>)input).ThenBy(x => GetPropertyValue(x, subContent[0].Trim()));
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == 0)
                input = input.OrderByDescending(x => GetPropertyValue(x, subContent[0].Trim()));
            else
                input = ((IOrderedEnumerable<T>)input).ThenByDescending(x => GetPropertyValue(x, subContent[0].Trim()));
        }
        i++;
    }

    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to do this but having problems with [Kjetil Watnedal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby#41262) because I don't use the inline linq syntax - I prefer method-style syntax. My specific problem was in trying to do dynamic sorting using a custom `IComparer`.

My solution ended up like this:

Given an IQueryable query like so:

```
List<DATA__Security__Team> teams = TeamManager.GetTeams();
var query = teams.Where(team => team.ID < 10).AsQueryable();
```

And given a run-time sort field argument:

```
string SortField; // Set at run-time to "Name"
```

The dynamic OrderBy looks like so:

```
query = query.OrderBy(item => item.GetReflectedPropertyValue(SortField));
```

And that's using a little helper method called GetReflectedPropertyValue():

```
public static string GetReflectedPropertyValue(this object subject, string field)
{
    object reflectedValue = subject.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(subject, null);
    return reflectedValue != null ? reflectedValue.ToString() : "";
}
```

---

One last thing - I mentioned that I wanted the `OrderBy` to use custom `IComparer` - because I wanted to do [Natural sorting](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/).

To do that, I just alter the `OrderBy` to:

```
query = query.OrderBy(item => item.GetReflectedPropertyValue(SortField), new NaturalSortComparer<string>());
```

See [this post](http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2009/09/natural-sort-compare-with-linq-orderby.html) for the code for `NaturalSortComparer()`.

Answer (score 9):

I've stumble this question looking for Linq multiple orderby clauses
and maybe this was what the author was looking for

Here's how to do that:

```
var query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name).ThenByDescending(pet => pet.Age);
```

Comment: +1 canceled the down-vote due to lack of explanation.  I also think the author might have been interested in multiple order-bys.  Even if dynamic *was* the key word, no reason to down-vote.

Answer (score 9):

After a lot of searching this worked for me:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> source, 
                                                    string orderByProperty, bool desc)
{
    string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    var type = typeof(TEntity);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, 
                                           new[] { type, property.PropertyType },
                                           source.AsQueryable().Expression, 
                                           Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return source.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

Comment: Exact solution that i would like to use...

Answer (score 9):

Use dynamic `linq`

just add `using System.Linq.Dynamic;`

And use it like this to order all your columns:

```
string sortTypeStr = "ASC"; // or DESC
string SortColumnName = "Age"; // Your column name
query = query.OrderBy($"{SortColumnName} {sortTypeStr}");
```

Comment: So how about a real life example, with a few joins?

Answer (score 6):

First Install Dynamic 
**Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console**

```
install-package System.Linq.Dynamic
```

Add **Namespace** `using System.Linq.Dynamic;`

Now you can use `OrderBy("Name, Age DESC")`

Comment: How can I use it with inner property sorting - like OrderBy("Branch.BranchName","Descending")

Comment: This works for me. Perhaps because the question is 10 years old, and this easier method only came later.

Answer (score 5):

You could add it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy( this IEnumerable<T> input, string queryString) {
    //parse the string into property names
    //Use reflection to get and sort by properties
    //something like

    foreach( string propname in queryString.Split(','))
        input.OrderBy( x => GetPropertyValue( x, propname ) );

    // I used Kjetil Watnedal's reflection example
}
```

The `GetPropertyValue` function is from [Kjetil Watnedal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby#41262)

The issue would be why? Any such sort would throw exceptions at run-time, rather than compile time (like D2VIANT's answer).

If you're dealing with Linq to Sql and the orderby is an expression tree it will be converted into SQL for execution anyway.

Comment: GetPropertyValue mehotod will be executed for all elements, it's bad solution.

Comment: `OrderBy` don't maintain the previous order!!

Answer (score 4):

Here's something else I found interesting.
If your source is a DataTable, you can use dynamic sorting without using Dynamic Linq

```
DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
                                         orderby order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate")
                                         select order;
DataView view = query.AsDataView();
bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669083.aspx (Using DataSetExtensions)

Here is one more way to do it by converting it to a DataView:

```
DataTable contacts = dataSet.Tables["Contact"];    
DataView view = contacts.AsDataView();    
view.Sort = "LastName desc, FirstName asc";    
bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the IEnumerable to IQueryable.

```
items = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Name ASC");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
        public List<Book> Books(string orderField, bool desc, int skip, int take)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(Book).GetProperty(orderField);

    return _context.Books
        .Where(...)
        .OrderBy(p => !desc ? propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null) : 0)
        .ThenByDescending(p => desc ? propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null) : 0)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: A couple of years later and I stumble upon this; this worked for me, like a dream. I have dynamic sorting on 1 to 3 properties, and this works like a dream. Easy to implement and hassle free.

Comment: Love this answer, but how can I make this work if I need to sort by a property of a child class?

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution uses the following class/interface.  It's not truly dynamic, but it works.

```
public interface IID
{
    int ID
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public static class Utils
{
    public static int GetID<T>(ObjectQuery<T> items) where T:EntityObject, IID
    {
        if (items.Count() == 0) return 1;
        return items.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID).FirstOrDefault().ID + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Maarten ([Query a collection using PropertyInfo object in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431546/query-a-collection-using-propertyinfo-object-in-linq)) I got this solution:

```
myList.OrderByDescending(x => myPropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
```

In my case I was working on a "ColumnHeaderMouseClick" (WindowsForm) so just found the specific Column pressed and its correspondent PropertyInfo:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo column in (new Process()).GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (column.Name == dgvProcessList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
    {}
}
```

OR

```
PropertyInfo column = (new Process()).GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == dgvProcessList.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name).First();
```

(be sure to have your column Names matching the object Properties)

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a response to the comments that need an example for the solution provided by  [@John Sheehan - Runscope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735/3142139)

> Please provide an example for the rest of us.

in DAL (Data Access Layer),

**The IEnumerable version:**

```
public  IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders()
{
    // i use Dapper to return IEnumerable<T> using Query<T>
    //.. do stuff

    return orders  // IEnumerable<Order>
}
```

**The IQueryable version**

```
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrdersAsQuerable()
{
    IEnumerable<Order> qry= GetOrders();

    // use the built-in extension method  AsQueryable in  System.Linq namespace
    return qry.AsQueryable();            
}
```

Now you can use the IQueryable  version to bind, for example GridView in Asp.net and benefit for sorting (you can't sort using IEnumerable version)

I used Dapper as ORM and build IQueryable version and utilized sorting in GridView in asp.net  so easy.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a dictionary from string to Func<> like this :

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Item, object>> SortParameters = new Dictionary<string, Func<Item, object>>()
{
    {"Rank", x => x.Rank}
};
```

And use it like this :

```
yourList.OrderBy(SortParameters["Rank"]);
```

In this case you can dynamically sort by string.

Comment: Nice! Really simple option for those of who can't use Dynamic Linq lib.

Comment: Nide! This is simple and work for me

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this for multiple order by

```
IOrderedEnumerable<JToken> sort;

if (query.OrderBys[0].IsDESC)
{
    sort = jarry.OrderByDescending(r => (string)r[query.OrderBys[0].Key]);
}
else
{
    sort = jarry.OrderBy(r =>
        (string) r[query.OrderBys[0].Key]); 
}

foreach (var item in query.OrderBys.Skip(1))
{
    if (item.IsDESC)
    {
        sort = sort.ThenByDescending(r => (string)r[item.Key]);
    }
    else
    {
        sort = sort.ThenBy(r => (string)r[item.Key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert List to IEnumerable or Iquerable, add using System.LINQ.Dynamic namespace, then u can mention the property names in comma seperated string to OrderBy Method which comes by default from System.LINQ.Dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to do this with the code below. No need write long and complex code.

```
 protected void sort_array(string field_name, string asc_desc)
        {

            objArrayList= Sort(objArrayList, field_name, asc_desc);
        }

        protected List<ArrayType> Sort(List<ArrayType> input, string property, string asc_desc)
        {
            if (asc_desc == "ASC")
            {

                return input.OrderBy(p => p.GetType()
                                           .GetProperty(property)
                                           .GetValue(p, null)).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return input.OrderByDescending(p => p.GetType()
                                               .GetProperty(property)
                                               .GetValue(p, null)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Specification (such as [Ardalis Specification](https://github.com/ardalis/Specification))

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TestExtensions;

public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyOrder<T>(ISpecificationBuilder<T> query, string propertyName, bool ascendingOrder)
    {
        if (ascendingOrder)
            query.OrderBy(T => EF.Property<object>(T!, propertyName));
        else
            query.OrderByDescending(T => EF.Property<object>(T!, propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Because this doesn't answer the question: "Is there any way to get this functionality on `IEnumerable<T>`?". Questions on Stack Overflow are not answered by offering alternatives to what people are doing because that could go on and on. We only do that if the approach in the question is clearly hopeless.

Comment: I answered because I had the same problem, and I added if to the answer... Though, thanks for clearing why you down-voted.

Answer (score -1):

With Net6 and EF

```
.AsQueryable().OrderBy((ColumnOrder.Column, ColumnOrder.Dir));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var result1 = lst.OrderBy(a=>a.Name);// for ascending order. 
 var result1 = lst.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Name);// for desc order.
```